# Use object in different function Delphi

Tags: delphi, class, object, delphi-2010

This is just a very simple question to which i can't find a good clear answer to. I don't quite have the time to read all the documentation for this since i'm in a time crunch.

But here it is.

I have made a new class on top of my TForm class like so:

```
 Bucket = Class
   glass: Integer;
   steel: Integer;
 End;
```

I then create a couple of objects in a method which belongs to TForm1

```
procedure TForm1.getMarbles;
var
  objPlastic: Bucket;
  objAlu: Bucket;

begin
  // Initialize objects
  objPlastic := Bucket.Create;
  objAlu := Bucket.Create;

  // Get Values from edtBox
  val(Edit1.Text, objPlastic.steel, code);
  val(Edit2.Text, objAlu.steel, code);
  val(Edit3.Text, objPlastic.glass, code);
  val(Edit4.Text, objAlu.glass, code);
end;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use these objects in other methods. I tried defining them in every way i know so far in the other methods I want to use them in, but I can't get it to work.

Here is the method and what I have it currently set to (which returns 0 all the time):

```
procedure TForm1.marbleDrop(kind: string);
var
  objPlastic: Bucket;
  I: Integer;
begin
  objPlastic := Bucket.Create;
  if kind= 'plastic' then // the function is receiving this parameter
  begin
    for I := 0 to objPlastic.glass do
    begin
      showmessage(inttostr(objPlastic.glass)); //returns 0
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Sorry for this kind of question, but i couldn't find a better way.

BTW, this is a simplified version of the code I am using. I did my best to get out any typos since it's a translation of what I am actually using, but it's mainly about the idea. I don't have typos in my code in delphi.

Comment: why using val ? mayeb you'd use StrToInt instead ? why using objects, maybe record would suffice ?

Comment: I always get confronted with that; The reason is because when I first started my questions were apparently vague and I didn't get any usable answers.

Comment: You can reduce their vagueness, so they can have real answers, or delete them...
Also, when you reply to someone's comment - start your reply with twitter-like "@username" sequence. So thet the user would get the notificatio nof your answer.

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm doing that as of lately. ;)

Comment: also please - edit your question and add the TAG for the certain delphi version you use // i meant you can reduce those question you already did posted to make those past question better and answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other to access the objects across methods, you have to either:

1. declare the objects as members of the Form class:

   ```
   type
     TForm1 = class(TForm);
     ...
     private
       objPlastic: Bucket;
       objAlu: Bucket;
     ...
     end;

   procedure TForm1.getMarbles;
   begin
     // Initialize objects
     if objPlastic = nil then objPlastic := Bucket.Create;
     if objAlu = nil then objAlu := Bucket.Create;

     // Get Values from edtBox
     objPlastic.steel := StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, 0);
     objAlu.steel := StrToIntDef(Edit2.Text, 0);
     objPlastic.glass := StrToIntDef(Edit3.Text, 0);
     objAlu.glass := StrToIntDef(Edit4.Text, 0);
   end;

   procedure TForm1.marbleDrop(kind: string);
   begin
     if (kind = 'plastic') and (objPlastic <> nil) then
     begin
       ShowMessage(IntToStr(objPlastic.glass));
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. pass them as parameters of the methods themselves:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.getMarbles(objPlastic, objAlu: Bucket);
   begin
     // Get Values from edtBox
     if objPlastic <> nil then
     begin
       objPlastic.steel := StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, 0);
       objPlastic.glass := StrToIntDef(Edit3.Text, 0);
     end;
     if objAlu <> nil then
     begin
       objAlu.steel := StrToIntDef(Edit2.Text, 0);
       objAlu.glass := StrToIntDef(Edit4.Text, 0);
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.marbleDrop(objWhichKind: Bucket);
   begin
     if objWhichKind <> nil then
     begin
       ShowMessage(IntToStr(objWhichKind.glass));
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.someMethod();
   var
     objPlastic: Bucket;
   begin
     objPlastic := Bucket.Create;
     getMarbles(objPlastic, nil);
     marbleDrop(objPlastic);
     objPlastic.Free;
   end;
   ```

Comment: You are a true hero! I'm curious though, why do you use nil and <>? What does that do? Is that to check whether the object exists or not?

Comment: exactly!

that is why i suggested records instead - for such simple data like pair of integers making objects is overkill

Comment: @Ortix92 BTW, option 1 leaks memory too - it allocates objects but never frees them. So if you would create/free the form numerous times - that would leek two objects on each occasion.

Comment: @Arioch'The: I left the freeing up to the `...` portion of code.  You can add a destructor or OnDestroy event handler to the Form to handle that.

Comment: @Remy i would not ask questions like that - and topic starter would not even saw the error and would not manage to do it in proper place, if pointed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it returns zero. It is another object. You should pass it as you pass any other parameter variable. What you made is similar to

```
procedure TForm1.Drop1(kind: string);
begin
   marbleDrop(); // here kind = "staal"
end;

procedure TForm1.marbleDrop();
var
  kind: string;
begin
  if kind = 'plastic' then // it is not !!! why ???
  begin
....
  end;
end;
```

---

You also has another problem - [Memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

```
  val(Edit4.Text, objAlu.glass, code);
end;
```

You just created two objects - and allocated [Heap memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_memory) for them.
But you **did not freed them**. That is garbage left and it will grow and grow and grow - until the program would exhaust all Windows memory and be killed.

If you want to use memory without any accuracy and without "wasting" your time on thinking and learning - you'd better user some managed language running in virtual machine, like PHP, Python, Java and other JVM-based, C# and other .NEt-based.

To make good Delphi code you should have at least some understanding what you CPU does and why.

---

Specifically in your code you'd better

1. use records instead of classes
2. pass them as `const-` or `var-`parameters to avoid redundant copying.

Like that:

```
type TBucket = Record  glass, steel: Integer; End;
type TForm1 = class (TForm) 
     .....
 private
   var objPlastic, objAlu: TBucket;
    (* making variables more global: now they are form-local not function-local *)
......

procedure TForm1.getMarbles;
begin
   objPlastic.steel := StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, 0);
   objAlu.steel := ...
   Self.objPlastic.glass ...  (* adding Self - just for clarity where those variable are taken from *)
   Self.objAlu.glass ....
end; 

procedure TForm1.marbleDrop(kind: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if kind = 'plastic' then // the function is receiving this parameter
  begin
    for I := 0 to Self.objPlastic.glass do
    begin
      showmessage(inttostr(objPlastic.glass)); 
        //getting via common parent context - TForm1 object, referenced as Self pseudo-variable
      marbleTell(objPlastic); // passing as parameter
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.marbleTell(const arg: TBucket);
// do not forget to use const to pass variable by-reference not by-value
begin
   showmessage(inttostr(arg.glass)); // getting via argument
end;
```

Comment: this doesn't make much sense to me... Can't I just call the object inside the method like in PHP? Otherwise I have to pass 10 parameters (and probably more). In php I would use $this->object..

Comment: this object should belong to somewhere - where to ? in your code it belonged to the getMarbles procedure. As the procedure ended - you lost all the references to the object. in marbleDrop you created yet another objects with the same name - who care about name?

what i did here is made those variables Form-global, so that you can use them from any Form method. you can also make them unit-global variables outside TForm1 class - but global variables lead to spaghetti code.

Comment: `$this` is `Self` in Delphi. I did exactly that - moved your variables to the object, not to the function.

Comment: Well thing is, I have until friday to get this code up and running for a project. I don't have time to do things differently. I HAVE to use delphi for this project but I didn't finish the course yet.

Comment: @Ortix92 That's nonsense. You don't have time to do things differently? In which case submit what you have. Which doesn't work. So you don't want to do that. And now you are stuck. You don't want to fix the problem, but you do want to fix the problem.

Comment: @Ortix92 in such consitions you'd make bug-ridden ugly slow code that would work enough to show to boss, but who knows how badly would run in production in long-term. So some basics you would have to know. At least open VCL sources and look patterns used there, about form-local objects for example. You'd better copy good patterns from there even if u would use them badly rather than ivent bad patterns and use them badly both :-) And after friday - FLEE (avoid responsibility) :-) or re-work the project in more relaxed pace. Because there anyway are things that you'd learn, easy or hard way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, It's not nonsense. I was on a tight deadline for friday and I needed a quick fix to get this functionality off the ground. It's for a SCHOOL project. I could care less about coding conventions at such a stressing time.

Comment: I read your comment as meaning, "I don't have time to change anything, but I need to fix my code." Which seems like a contradiction to me.

Comment: Brushing you teeth is not "coding convention". It is the regular investment of little (but continuous, regular) amount of time to avoid much larger problems in future.